# How to do an aggregated OR on a column in Amazon Redshift

Tags: aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift

I have a table with user browsing data and a column indicating if certain action has been found. The column is of boolean type, which made a perfect sense when designing.

In order to check if a visitor made an *action*, I'm currently doing something like

```
SELECT
   date,
   user_id,
   max(CASE WHEN user_action THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) action_found
FROM
   browsing_history
GROUP BY
   date,
   user_id;
```

I don't really like this since a *columnar OR* would solve the problem. So, is there some sort of aggregating OR function in Redshift that I'm unaware of?

Thanks

Comment: What don't you like about it? Are you worried about performance? Do you want to include users who did not complete an action in the result set?

Comment: I don't like using MAX here, but currently it has to be used since Redshift doesn't have the function for doing a column-wise (aggregated on the group level) OR. What I wrote does the job - I don't like it though and was wondering if someone knows about a dedicated function for it (which I'm unable to find).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BOOL_OR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BOOL_OR.html)?...[examples (at the end)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_bitwise_examples.html)

```
SELECT date, user_id, bool_or(user_action)::int action_found
FROM browsing_history
GROUP BY date, user_id;
```

BOOL values can be cast to INTs:

```
select ('t'::bool)::int t, ('f'::bool)::int f;
 t | f
---+---
 1 | 0
```

So if you're just looking for a bit cleaner syntax you could do:

```
SELECT date, user_id, max(user_action::int) action_found
FROM browsing_history
GROUP BY date, user_id;
```

Or use SUM:

```
sum(user_action::int)>0 -- BOOL result
(sum(user_action::int)>0)::int -- INT result
```

UPDATE: The documentation is a bit sparse and I don't know why they put it under bitwise aggregate functions, but I think bool_or does what you want.

```
with actions as (
    select 1 as id, 't'::bool as did union all
    select 1 as id, 'f'::bool as did union all
    select 2 as id, 'f'::bool as did union all
    select 2 as id, 'f'::bool as did union all
    select 3 as id, 't'::bool as did union all
    select 3 as id, 't'::bool as did
)
select id, bool_or(did) did_any, bool_and(did) did_all
from actions group by id order by id

 id | did_any | did_all
----+---------+---------
  1 | t       | f
  2 | f       | f
  3 | t       | t
```

Comment: It seems like this works on all the bits for a single value in one row. What I need is to aggregate all boolean values in one column over all rows on a certain group level.

Comment: @hummingBird -- `bool_or()` will also work on groups. Did you try it and get a failure?

Comment: Well, I read description and figured it's not what I'm looking for. My bad - I checked and everything is working great! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool_or()` for the equivalent of `max()` or `bool_and()` for the equivalent of `min()`. See the `Data Types` section of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MAX.html).

> The Boolean equivalent of the MIN function is the BOOL_AND Function, and the Boolean equivalent of MAX is the BOOL_OR Function.